# How can I fix a "*.sty not found" error in Lyx, when it works in pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, lyx, packages

I've just installed a [gantt chart package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-gantt/), which I'm trying to use it in LyX.

I attempted to use the [first minimal example](http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=Projects:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots), but this failed in LyX with `LaTeX Error: File 'forloop.sty' not found.` However, compiling the pdf from raw LaTeX works fine. I attempted both creating the example file from scratch, and exporting the LaTeX (plain) from LyX, and attempting a manual `pdflatex example.tex`. This worked in both cases.

Back in LyX, I tried following the [instructions](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/LaTeXErrors#file-not-found) on the wiki. Specifically,

```
$ kpsewhich forloop.sty
./forloop.sty
$ sudo texhash
texhash: Updating /etc/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

Then in LyX, Tools→Reconfigure and restart. It still failed with the same error. How can I fix this problem in LyX?

I'm using LyX 2.1.1 and on Arch Linux. pdflatex details are below.

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
...
Compiled with libpng 1.6.13; using libpng 1.6.13
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.26.5
```

### Details of the LyX file

I created a new LyX file, and put the following into the header.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gantt}
```

I then created ERT and copy pasted from the first minimal example [here](http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=Projects:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots), from `\begin{gantt}{10}{12}` to `\end{gantt}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you did not install the `forloop.sty` file correctly, but just save it to the folder, where you have your project. If this is the case, it will work with `pdflatex`, as `pdflatex` will install search you current directory for `.sty` files, but LyX will not. To install a package you have to choices. You can use the texlive install utitlity, if the package is aviliable in the texlive mirror.

```
tlmgr install <package1> <package2>
```

If not you need to create a new `texmf` folder (typically in `~/texmf/`) and then make a subfolder in `~/texmf/tex/latex/forloop/` and save your `forloop.sty` file to there. Then run

```
texhash ~/texmf
```

For TeX to recognize your package

Comment: Sorry, I was halfway typing a response to your comment. `locate forloop.sty` finds nothing at all on my system. Oddly enough, pdf creation still works with from the command line though.

Comment: Locate only works if you manually updated the system file database (nothing to do with latex, update using sudo updatedb). For latex files use kpsewhich file.sty

Comment: @daleif Yes, sorry, I did `sudo updatedb` first. However, I've just realised that half my problem was I was running the cli `pdflatex` from `/tmp`, which *did* contain `forloop.sty`. It's all working now (although I'm still clueless as to why LyX didn't work even after I'd applied the fixes as per my question).

Comment: "You can use the texlive install utitlity" => Do all people who installed texlive have this? I can't find it.

Comment: If you installed texlive you should have it.